# Adding a button that removes itself and the line it is attached to

Tags: javascript, button

I'm not very advanced in javascript.  I've been trying to write a script that adds a line of text, along with a button that removes itself and the attached line of text. 
While I have managed the text part without problem I am having a lot of problem with the button. 
Whenever I try to add the function that removes the elements to the button, the script keeps working but the created elements never appear(it seems that the button immediately deletes itself and the text, which shouldn't happen without being clicked).

```js
var numberId=0;
function add(){
         console.log("add");
            var te = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
            var d=document.createElement("tekst");
            var bu=document.createElement("button");
            var t=document.createTextNode(te);
            d.appendChild(t);
            d.id="a"+numberId;
            document.getElementById("hereGoesResult").appendChild(d);
            d.appendChild(bu);
            function placeholderFunction(){
          console.log("placeholder");
                deletusTheTextus(d.id);
            }
            but.addEventListener("click",placeholderFunction());
        numberId++;
}
function deletsTheText(a){
         console.log("delets");
            var elem = document.getElementById(a);
            elem.remove();
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv = "Content-type" charset = "utf-8">
      <title > Sample HTML5 File</title>
      <script src="scripts.js">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
       Enter:
       <input type="text" id="textInput"> <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"><br>
      </form>
      <div id="hereGoesResult">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sorry for mistakes, I'm posting for the first time
(variables have bad names because I had to quickly edit them, my usual ones are a little too silly for being posted on stackoverflow)

Comment: Please provide a **complete** example. In this case, you should include the minimal HTML required for the JavaScript code to run.

Comment: What a terrible way of naming your variables

Comment: Please provide the HTML also.

Comment: By the way, you have duplicate IDs. All the newly added elements have the same ID, `"a"`. That's not gonna work. Just get rid of that ID, and use `button.parentElement.remove()` to remove the whole row including the button.

Comment: I omitted the html and unique ID generation for the sake of not including too much code, added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call your `placeholderFunction` while trying to register it as event handler. So this:

```
but.addEventListener("click", placeholderFunction())
```

should look like this:

```
but.addEventListener("click", placeholderFunction);
```

Next thing is, you write `bu` for your button variable but try to attach and eventlistener to `but`. Also make sure you call `deletsTheText` inside `placeholderFunction`, not `deletusTheTextus` ;-)